# Using a CALayer as a mask to a backing layer of a GLKView blocks touch events?

Tags: objective-c, calayer, cashapelayer

I'm trying to use a CAShapeLayer as a mask to the backing layer of a GLKView like so:

```
CGRect circleFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 800, 800);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleFrame];
CGPoint circleAnchor = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleFrame) / CGRectGetMaxX(circleFrame),CGRectGetMidY(circleFrame) / CGRectGetMaxY(circleFrame));

shapeLayerMask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayerMask.path = path.CGPath;
shapeLayerMask.anchorPoint = circleAnchor;
shapeLayerMask.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,800, 800);
shapeLayerMask.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

shapeLayerMask.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayerMask.opacity = 1.0f;
shapeLayerMask.hidden = NO;

self.view.layer.mask = shapeLayerMask;
```

But as soon as i do this, all my touch events stop firing. No more touchesBegan, touchesEnded, etc. Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance!